# KeyError: None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]

Tags: python, string, split

Data frame

| name | date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc 012 | 2023-08-14 | 1 |

Creating df

df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from table", engine)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

creating a new column using split(), and getting following error

df[['tag']] = df['name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[[0]]

expected output:

| name | date | flag | tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc 012 | 2023-08-14 | 1 | abc |

But I am getting Error:

```
df[['tag']] = df['name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[[0]]
```

File "/opt/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3464, in **getitem**
indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
File "/opt/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1314, in _get_listlike_indexer
self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
File "/opt/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1374, in _validate_read_indexer
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: `myDict = {'name':['abc 123'], 'date': ['2023-08-14'], 'flag': [1]}`
`df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myDict)`
`df[['tag']] = df['name'].str.split(' ', expand=True)[[0]]` This code works for me. So you need to give more info. How do you create your dataframe?

Comment: have done the required changes, please check. I am reading from sql db and changing date column format

Comment: @Sabsa is (correctly) pointing out that on your very limited example `df`, the line in question does not throw the apparent error at all. I.e., the request is for you to isolate a (small!) portion of your `df`, on which the line does throw this error, so that SO users can reproduce it and actually help with finding a solution. The additional information provided does not change that situation.